# Unable to build android in ionic in ubuntu16.04

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I was unable to take  an android  build from ionic in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

installed ionic by

`npm install -g cordova ionic`

and

`ionic start myApp tabs`

also downloaded Android SDK and set `ANDROID_HOME` in `.bashrc`

by

`export ANDROID_HOME="/home/arun/softzz/android-sdk/tools"`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/arun/softzz/android-sdk/add-ons`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/arun/softzz/android-sdk/platform-tools`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/arun/softzz/android-sdk/build-tools`

and downloaded the `sdk 21` platform-tools and build-tools

Also in terminal, I have exported the path by

`export ANDROID_HOME=/home/arun/softzz/android-sdk`
`PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
`PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools`
`PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`

On my project folder from command-line

`ionic platform android`
`ionic build android`

which gives me following error

`Running command: /home/arun/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/arun/myApp`

`add to body class: platform-android`

`Running command: /home/arun/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build`

`/home/arun/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;`
                    ^

`Error: Failed to run "ant -version", make sure you have ant installed and added to your PATH.
    at /home/arun/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js:43:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:220:5)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)`

`ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/arun/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project`

`Error: /home/arun/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/share/cordova-cli/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)`

Comment: I have set ANDROID_HOME in `.profile` too

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution 
by installing `ant`
by `sudo apt-get install ant`

the only problem is that i want to export the path every time i need to take a build
.
Any solution for that ??